# Define NavigationDrawer behavior

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, androidx

I'm currently trying to understand how does the AndroidX artifacts implements the Navigation Drawer. I've created a new Activity using the Android Studio template for the Navigation Drawer Activity, and in the MainActivity class I can't find the setNavigationItemSelectedListener method.
I need to know where to define which fragment is showed when I select some item in the Navigation menu.
I'm currently using Android Studio 3.5.1

My MainActivity class looks like:

```
package cu.me.cuantotengo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

but you can try it by starting the template of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [NavigationUI documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui), the `android:id` of the menu item in your menu is matched with the `android:id` of a destination in the navigation graph in the `res/navigation` directory.

Therefore if you want to change what Fragment is loaded when you select a menu item, you should change your navigation graph file and replace the `android:name` on the destination with the name of the Fragment class you want.

Comment: It worked, thanks, but what should I do if I want to launch another activity or do something else, like customize animations, etc?

Comment: You can use an `<activity>` destination to start activities. NavigationUI always uses the animation specified by the Material Design guidelines, but you can certainly set your own `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` after the call to `setupWithNavController()` call and conditionally call [`onNavDestinationSelected()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.html#onNavDestinationSelected(android.view.MenuItem,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)) to get the default behavior